# Go back to starting view

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

My iPhone app has an initial screen, then the main screen, and then a final summary screen.  When the user clicks "Start Over" on the summary screen, I want to go back to the starting screen.  How can I do that?

I can close this summary screen using:

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

But how do I go back to that initial screen?

Thanks,

-Scott

Comment: Initial screen means you're saying splash screen?

Comment: If you are using `pushViewController` to show the next view. Then try using `popToRootViewController` or `popToViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement **UiNavigationController** and use its **popToRootViewControllerAnimated:** property.

and study UiNavigationController class reference properly for understand it better-
 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I switched to using storyboards and am using **performSegueWithIdentifier** to move forward and **dismissViewControllerAnimated** to move back.